# Split string by number of whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like either of these three examples:

```
1: Name             = astring               Some comments
2: Typ              = one two thee             Must be "sand", "mud" or "bedload"
3: RDW    = 0.02      [ - ] Some comment about RDW
```

I first split the variable name and rest like so:

```
re.findall(r'\s*([a-zA-z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*(.*)', line)
```

I then want to split the right part of the string into a part containing the values and a part containing the comments (if there are any). I want to do this by looking at the number of whitespaces. If it exceeds say 4, then I assume the comments to start

Any idea on how to do this?

I currently have

```
re.findall(r'(?:(\S+)\s{0,3})+', dataString)
```

However if I test this using the string:

```
'aa    aa23r234rf2134213^$&$%&            bb'
```

Then it also selects 'bb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single regex with `re.findall`:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?:(?:\s{4,}|\[)(.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkUk3J/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)`  - capturing group #1 matching 1 or more letters/digits/underscores
- `\s*=\s*` - `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - capturing group #2 matching any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
- `(?:(?:\s{4,}|\[)(.*))?` - an optional group matching

  - `(?:\s{4,}|\[)` - 4 or more whitespaces or a `[`
  - `(.*)` - capturing group #3 matching 0+ chars up to
- `$` - the end of string.

Comment: Maybe add the ending symbol?

Comment: @Adirio: It is not necessary, `.*` (a *greedily* quantified dot) will match up to the end of the string (or line if `re.M` is used).

Comment: I know its not needed, but it makes that point clear for non-used users.

Comment: That looks really good and works in my example but I forgot to give one extra example: sometimes there is also a situation like so: varnam = value  [-] etc.

Comment: In this last comment I tried to show that a comment is either started with a bracket ([) or 4 or more spaces. Is it possible to incoporate this?

Comment: This seems to work: ^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?:\s{4,}|\[)(?:.*) however I sometimes don't have a comment at all, the it doesn't work..

Comment: I have tried to update the answer, I am on a mobile.